# Leaving Europe via Spain with a BNL2 Visa Type D

Tags: visas, schengen, long-stay-visas

My stay in the Netherlands should have been for one year, but circumstances forced me to go back to my country early.

I decided to go back using the bus, and consequently, I had to travel from the Netherlands to Spain, and then on to Morocco.

Would this create a problem to me because I didn't realize until now that my visa was not Schengen and I was allowed to be in the Netherlands only?

The "Valid For" field says "Netherlands"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A type D visa allows you to visit all other Schengen countries within the 90/180 day rule. You have no problem.

Comment: By the way, the didn't stamp my passport when leaving Europe. Is this common?

Comment: @HalfLife when you leave the Schengen area you should normally get an exit stamp. If you didn't, you can use other evidence to show when you left, including your entry stamp for Morocco.